# how to close open ftp connections?

Tags: ftp, connection, filezilla

I use FileZilla, and I thought when a session ended, it automatically closed the ftp connection, but that doesn't appear to have happened because now I'm getting a "530 Sorry, the maximum number of connections (10) for your host are already connected." error.  Is there a way to find any open ftp connections and close them from my end?  Or, do I have to contact the host?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the other clients connect from the same IP. Also, if you want to close a connection, you can always use `tcpdrop(1)`:
`$ tcpdrop myhost.net:2353 example.com:ftp`

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, and most Unixen IIRC, there is the `netstat` utility.  By itself, it will show you what active connections there are.  For example:

```
$ netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 foo.example.com:uuidgen     nfs1.example.com:nfs        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 foo.example.com:ssh         bar.example.com:54993       ESTABLISHED 
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    88654  @/com/ubuntu/upstart
```

ans do forth.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can close it if you have access to a router using in this connection data transport.
2. You can change FileZilla to other program.
3. You can disconnect connections from ftp administration.
4. You can kill process handling that connections.